# Entity Framework error connecting to SQL Server Express after mounting/connecting in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server-express, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Just in case I am doing something wrong, I have uploaded a video so you can see every step I have done! I am able to reproduce this error.

[Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aPZNQLnJZU)

Basically - Start a new MVC 3 project and using EF in the normal way on a simple class.

I used the following connection string:

```
<add name="databaseconnection" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|database.mdf;User Instance=true;Initial Catalog=database" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I navigate to the site, **Everything** works ok and as expected.

Now, if I try to double click the .mdf database to open it inside of Visual Studio, all hell breaks loose!

I can connect and view the tables as expected, but even if I do nothing and just close (and/or) delete the connection, next time I go to the application, I get the following error:

> One or more files do not match the
>   primary file of the database. If you
>   are attempting to attach a database,
>   retry the operation with the correct
>   files.  If this is an existing
>   database, the file may be corrupted
>   and should be restored from a backup.
>   Cannot open database "database"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user
>   'WIL2-8EEA651803\Administrator'. Log
>   file 'c:\documents and
>   settings\administrator\my
>   documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestingEF\TestingEF\App_Data\database.ldf'
>   does not match the primary file.  It
>   may be from a different database or
>   the log may have been rebuilt
>   previously.

No matter what I try, I can't reconnect - the only thing I can do is to rename the database and initial catalog. I am sure that the previous version of the MVC Movie Database Tutorial (before they updated to using compact framework) worked fine like this, so I am unsure why I am having these issues.

So, my question is, what is causing this and what should I be doing instead?

Next, Error number 1 in the video, this is a quick XP VM I use for testing, and it happens at random, but did not happen this time and has never happened on the main machine - so I am curious, but not that bothered.  When attempting to build the Controller, I get the following error:

```
"Unable to retrieve metadata for 'TestingEF.Models.blabla'. The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."
```

Any idea what this is?

Comment: I would simply not use the "AttachDbFileName=" feature - attach your database file to a database server (possibly your local SQL Server Express) and connect there. This attach DB File stuff is just weird and messy and seems to cause a lot of issues.... (especially in combination with the `User Instance=true` setting...)

Comment: @marc_s - I am now using SQL Server CE connection string along with a data source, as in the MVC example and it works as expected... application fully works and I can edit the database at the same time. The ASP.Net Membership DB and other projects seem to work just fine with the other connection string... I am just not sure what EF has changed that makes it mess up now, but anyway, thanks... your other answer and this comment do give a little more insight to the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I know for the second issue I had to manully drop the database to get this to go away. I think it has to do with the model and the metadata for the model not being in sync int he database.

Comment: Also, check to make sure your config file has the proper connection string. It could be that it can't connect to the database.