# Trying to deploy an Entity Framework Code First application without much luck? Best Deployment strategy?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Despite a few hiccups and a few workarounds, my MVC based Entity Framework (Code First) application is now complete and ready for deployment.

I originally tried developing through SQL Express, however, I had non stop problems with the Code First approach as [I asked about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924553/entity-framework-error-connecting-to-sql-server-express-after-mounting-connecting) which made it completely unworkable.

So, in the end, I developed it following the majority of guidelines and used SQL Compact Edition. This has been absolutely brilliant for development - but - now it has come to deployment and I am stuck.

I have seen some people saying about generating the Schema from the `.SDF` file, however, there are differences and restrictions in Compact edition such as `nvarchar` being limited to a length of `4000`, and I need max in my application.

So basically, what can I do?

In addition - but not essential - , I am going to be moving on to the next project shortly, It will involve heavy usage of items needing to be stored in a database that are longer than 4000 characters. Are there any better strategies now for development / Is it possible to use Code First with SQL Server Express or SQL Full (I have MSDN and willing to install/use anything that will help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my unofficial recommendations:

- SQL CE is not a viable option for most production applications that are based on MVC (although I have used it in production services in rare cases).
- I would try to avoid switching databases between development and production - i.e., don't test on SQL CE and deploy to SQL Express or something else.
- I have never tried to open an MDF inside of Visual Studio - maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying here, but in general I'd recommend using the SQL Server-specific tools to manage databases: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/search.aspx?q=sql+server+management+studio+express.
- Regarding the other post, I would generally discourage using the AttachDBFilename portion of connection strings unless you need it for a specific purpose.
- It sounds like you may want to review the available database initialization strategies: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/03/31/configuring-database-initializers-in-a-config-file/.
- There are lots of walkthroughs on our blog and the MVC MSDN site - if those don't work for you feel free to reach out to us from our blog and provide feedback on what we can do better!

Our blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/
MVC walkthroughs: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part4-cs

Comment: Thank you so much for this... I will certainly look at other connection strings - it was always my intention to develop and host on SQL Server (Why I have a MSDN Sub)... As for SQL CE, I fully agree with you, but, I don't suppose you can tell others at MS?... Every guide that I have seen dealing with MVC/EF works with it - even the official ones... If you scroll down to the bottom of the page you linked to (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part4-cs) You will see that they use SQL CE! After my issues, I just decided to use it for an easy life! (1/3)

Comment: (and it solved all my problems, until now!) ... As for the third bullet point, If you read that link, a bit of clarification... I know/use/love Management studio, I just posted that link here as a reason why I am not using SQL at the moment... I like to live edit the data I am using / quickly add data. I know I can do it from Management Studio, however, I thought I should be able to do it directly from Visual Studio, after all, it connects and opens the database and allows me to do everything... it just seems to break/fail after that. Anyway,(2/3)

Comment: I am going to read through your links and hopefully try a better connection string and hopefully it will solve all this. If you are here because of the blog/email comment - Many thanks! ... (Currently reading your blog right now! Learning a lot from the beta/preview release posts) (3/3)

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand regarding deployment/migration you might want to take a look at http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

On the other hand I've been checking [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 Books Online](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/F/0/7F089D09-9002-4243-BF99-D3CCDE905CE0/ReadmeSQLServerCompact40_ENU.htm) and in principle there is no *known issues* with data types, although the limitation you mentioned for [`nvarchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) is confirmed.

Finally in order to elaborate a strategy you might find interesting the [Differences Between SQL Server Compact and SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The limit is here - http://i.imgur.com/ZmWR8.png - Basically, Compact edition seems to have a 4k max on length... It does not support MAX which SQL does. Checking your links now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a debug and a release specific `web.config` file:

- In the release specific file you remove the connection string, so it creates a database for you.
- In the debug specific file you keep the connection string.

However, I would suggest you to not use a connection string and use SQL Management Studio instead. Given that the Compact Edition does not support your requirement, this is a good time to switch...