# Converting Entity Framework connection string to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-express

My project has an Entity Framework connection string but I want to connect to a SQL Server Express database, so I think I have to change the connection string to SQL Server Express - but how ?

I want to change below connection string. Is it also enough connect database just changing connection string for same SQL Server mdf file ?

```
<add name="MyEntities"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.MyEntities.csdl|res://*/Model.MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/Model.TravldbEntities.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=sandiego;
                                Initial Catalog=mydatabse;Persist Security Info=True;
                                User ID=user;Password='password';MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried? I'm not familiar with EF, but why not just try something similar to how a normal C# app would connect:

```
<add name="MyEntities"
 connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    Data Source=sandiego; -- maybe needs to be sandiego\SQLEXPRESS?
    User ID=user;
    Password=password;">
```

I would only specify the MARS attribute if you know for sure you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 Data Source=sandiego
```

Use this:

```
 Data Source=SomeMachineNameOrIP\SQLExpress
```

Here's another [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116994/sql-express-connection-string-for-entity-framework-code-first/4117158#4117158).

Comment: If it is local mdf file ? Do i have to give full path ?

Comment: If you have a database already attached to a SQL Express instance, no it is not a path to an MDF file, it's a reference to an instance of SQL Server Express.