# ASP.NET MVC 3, SQL Server; Code First EF approach not adding tables to App_Data/.mdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-express

When you use the Code First EF approach and just point to ./SQLEXPRESS, EF nicely builds your tables for you, defines all the fields, etc.

But it doesn't seem to work that way when you direct your connection string to add an .MDF file in /App_Data instead.  Is that working as intended?  The tutorials I'm finding on this, [such as this one](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1), show the tables in the .MDF being created by hand.

But I have not seen any documentation anywhere plainly state that Code First EF will build your tables one way but not the other, so I'm frankly just confused.  Any illumination or advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

ETA: Okay, I see that this tutorial I linked is for the database-first approach, not code-first.  In other places I'm reading that EF should, in theory, populate an App_Data/.mdf file the same way.  But it still won't for me; if I give it an empty .mdf file to work with it refuses to add tables; if I don't give it an empty .mdf it tries to build one in my C:/Users/ directory.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: I've tried several connection strings.
`<add name="EFDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MLDatabase.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`
creates one type of exception.
Using `Initial Catalog` instead of `AttachDBFilename` creates another kind of exception.
I've also tried including `Database=EFDbContext;` in my connection string but it seems redundant since i have the `name` attribute.

Comment: You should have both `Initial Catalog` and `AttachDBFilename` inside your connection string. `name` is the name of the connection string, `Initial Catalog`/`Database` is the name of the database, and `AttachDBFilename` is the name of the file to store data in.

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116994/sql-express-connection-string-for-entity-framework-code-first) help? Seems like it might be the same issue.  As @Brice mentioned, it looks like you may need an Initial Catalog or database attribute in the connection string in order for EF to name the database correctly.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your input!  This is the connection string that finally worked:
`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=|DataDirectory|MLDatabase.mdf;Database=EFDbContext;User Instance=true`
Though, now I am having other strangenesses, such as, when I view `MLDatabase.mdf` in the Server Explorer, it won't list any tables, though I have been successfully viewing and updating a record in the database.