# Unable to connect to GoDaddy database server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am building an application using ASP.NET MVC and everything works fine on my local setup (localhost). I'm using GoDaddy for hosting and when I try to register as a user for my application, I get this error:

> Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.

So I checked my web.config and it does actually provide those two arguments/parameters in the connection string:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection"
  connectionString="Data Source=ip-of-database;
  AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\project-20151104031949.mdf;
  Initial Catalog=project-20151104031949;User Id=user; Password=password"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I am using the Entity Framework (code first).

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116994/sql-server-express-connection-string-for-entity-framework-code-first) Stackoverflow question as well as the documentation for ASP.NET deployment but either of them didn't really help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would think that GoDaddy would have some good examples of connection strings.  However, I don't think that you would attach to the mdf, you should specify a server\instance and initial catalog (which you have).

Comment: Clue:  https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-your-connection-strings-3323

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-your-connection-strings-3323 But I don't have access to that because it's a shared account. I tried the mdf out of desperation.

Comment: @RudyTheHunter I just finished commenting that I looked at that when you commented the link.